# Appscript: Renaming the url

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google sheet that uses Appscript to auto fill out a Google doc and inserts the url next to the data for that row.

I currently have it so it replaces the name of the url with a word but want it to be replaced with the data in that row instead.[Current ‘code’](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSFzX.png)

Comment: [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Don't use images for code. Why the java tag?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

cell.setFormula(`=HYPERLINK("${row[column number - 1]}","row[3]")`)